# Play 2 - The default ebeanServer has not been defined

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.2

I'm learning how to use Play framework, to get and set persistent objects.
I'm using JPA 2 with Hibernate implementation, while using Oracle DB.
I've read that Play manages the transactions through extending the model class.
I've added to the `build.sbt -> val appDependencies = Seq("org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.2.2.Final")`

To the application.conf I've added ->

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.default.url="whatever"
db.user....
db.pass....
ebean.datasource.default=DefaultDS
ebean.default="model.*"
ebean.datasource.factory=jndi
```

I've added `@Entity` annotation to my Person class, extended Model from `play.db.ebean.Model`, and in the main class created a new person and did `p.update();`

I'm getting `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined`.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 2):

With Play, you can use either Ebean or another JPA provider. The most straightforward solution is to use Ebean as it's better integrated with Play.

In this case, you don't need any hibernate dependency, you can remove it and just use the `javaEbean` one (and a dependency for you JDBC Driver of course).

In your `application.conf` you probably don't need JNDI-registered datasource, so something like this should be enough :

```
db.default.driver=...
db.default.url=...
db.default.user=...
db.default.password=...
ebean.default="model.*"
```